# SDWebImage UIButton setImageWithURL return small image on iOS6

Tags: ios, uibutton, sdwebimage

I use SDWebImage in my app for setting image for button. But when I try to do it

```
[self.buttonPhoto setImageWithURL:self.user.avatarURL forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I see that image twice smaller, than it should be.

[image]

To compare I write setting local image for button

```
[self.buttonPhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sara"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In this case I see normal picture.

[image]

May be you know about this problem and know solution? Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

try to use placeholder for the image with this method:

```
[Button setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about actual image size. Image dimension was 35x35px, when button frame - 70x70px. And I don't why, but UIButton doesn't want scale such images.